# Inject value to module after bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I want to use [angular-ui for google maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-map/). From the example, it passes a hard-coded coordinate.

```
$scope.mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.784, -78.670),
  zoom: 15,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

Then use it on the directive.

```
<div id="map_canvas" ui-map="myMap" class="map" ... ui-options="mapOptions">
</div>
```

But I need the coordinates to be the user location, to get that, I need to use `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` which I got the coordinate in a callback.

I'm thinking of something like:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(result) {
    angular.bootstrap(myElement, ['myModule']); // I need a way to inject "result" to the module
}, function(error) {
  // fallback to default coordinate.
});
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the constant to the module before bootstrapping:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.controller('MyController', function($scope, coordinates){
  $scope.coordinates = coordinates;
})

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(result) {
    angular.module('myModule').constant('coordinates', result);
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myModule']);
}, function(error) {
  // fallback to default coordinate.
});
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/MejKqelVze7l7ioXIvDn?p=preview)